# How to append values to an existing in a new column

Tags: sql-server

I am having multiple Id's in my table i have to append value such 00,01,02...99.

```
id
1768053
1768054
1768055
1768059
1771340
1771341
1771342
1771343
1771344
1771345
1771346
1771347
1771348
1774628
1774629
1768053
1768054
1768055
1768059
1771340
1771341
1771342
1771343
1771344
1771345
1771346
1771347
1771348
1774628
1774629
1768053
1768054
1768055
1768059
1771340
1771341
1771342
1771343
1771344
1771345
1771346
1771347
1771348
1774628
1774629
```

Above i gave how i have id's in my table.

```
id                  newid
1768053             176805300
1768053             176805301
1768053             176805302
1768053             176805303
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
1768053             176805399
```

I want newid as i have shown above in sql.Please me as soon as possible.

Comment: what is the datatype of the id column?

Comment: datatype of id is varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id)`:

```
SELECT id
     , id * 100 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS newid
FROM t
```

Sample output:

```
| id      | newid     |
|---------|-----------|
| 1768053 | 176805300 |
| 1768053 | 176805301 |
| 1768053 | 176805302 |
| 1768054 | 176805400 | <- resets to 0
| 1768054 | 176805401 |
| 1768054 | 176805402 |
| 1768055 | 176805500 | <- resets to 0
| 1768055 | 176805501 |
```

This assumes that you do not have more than 100 duplicates for a specific id e.g. the value 1768053 cannot be repeated more than 100 times, otherwise just multiply by 1000 instead.

Answer (score 0):

For `VARCHAR` data type you can try like following.

```
SELECT id + Replicate('0', 2-Len(rn)) + rn AS NewId 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               Cast(Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY id) - 1 AS VARCHAR) RN 
        FROM   [yourtablename])t
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/PKMF50250)